# mysql utf 8 and characters like ñ,á,é doesn´t insert

Tags: php, mysql, apache, zend-framework, utf-8

Hi i´m developing an aplication in mysql the value of my variables is this

```
 character_set_client     | utf8
 character_set_connection | utf8
 character_set_database   | utf8
 character_set_filesystem | binary
 character_set_results    | utf8
 character_set_server     | utf8
 character_set_system     | utf8
 character_sets_dir       | C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\MySQL55\share\charsets\
----------------------+-----------------
 Variable_name        | Value
----------------------+-----------------
 collation_connection | utf8_general_ci
 collation_database   | utf8_general_ci
 collation_server     | utf8_general_ci
```

*So everything is in utf 8 , but when i insert characters like ñ,á,é *

```
mysql> insert into falla values(null,'ñ');
```

ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xA4' for column 'FALLA' at row 1

i have configured everything to utf8, the apache default charset, php ini and the aplication , rigth now i´m doing the insertions in the console but i have those errors , changing the collation to spanish will help? in the character_set_dir i cant find any file that has utf8 like name.

Comment: what about charset for column `FALLA`

Comment: when i show show full columns i get  FALLA    | varchar(50) | utf8_general_ci | I think that´s not the probles because the database was created in utf8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'\xA4'` suggests that it is your console encoding that is the problem...  (in UTF8 "ñ" should be `\xc3\xb1`)

**edit:**

perhaps you could try

```
INSERT INTO falla VALUES(null, '\xc3\xb1');
```

and see how that works out for you :)

Comment: not an expert on Windows 8 (or Windows in general, for several years now), but have a look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8

Comment: thee autorun file didn´t exist so i created it with the values chcp 65001 but now every time i insert any utf character my console not recognises it from the keyboard and then it restarts are you sure this is a console encoding problem?

Comment: You had all the reason it was my terminal then i switched to add the strings in myPHPAdmin and all the ñ´s where there !!!

Answer (score 0):

Change **utf8** charset of table, database, column to **utf8mb4** and collate **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**